# error while running node.js program

Tags: cygwin, node.js, serverside-javascript, npm

I am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/tree/2a8725f089ef052ec8b4ccfed8f6fbece70a606a#) program on my window system but i am getting this error .

```
Administrator@rahul ~/nodepad
$ node app.js
native library not built
Express server listening on port 3000, environment: development
Using connect 0.5.9, Express 1.0.7, Jade 0.6.3

node.js:50
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: EPERM, Operation not permitted
    at Stream._onConnect (net.js:687:18)
    at IOWatcher.onWritable [as callback] (net.js:284:12)
```

Please suggest why this errror is coming .

Thanks

Comment: @generalhenry node 0.3.1 version of node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you started a mongodb instance? Nodepad app requires a MongoDB database to work.

Get a precompiled package from http://www.mongodb.org, unzip and create a "data" directory. then run "mongod --dbpath ./data" from the bin dir (use your 'data' path).

Sometimes Node.js stacktraces are cryptic.

Comment: while running mogodb and then node app.js gives me the same error. and while running mongod --dbpath ./data gives me the error that dbpath not exist? does dbpath is required?

Comment: Just download MongoDB from http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-1.6.5.zip, unpack it into a dir. Create a "data" directory inside the bin directory and run "mongod --dbpath data". Now run the Nodepad app (install its module requirements using npm). Works fine here.

Comment: thanks now application is running but while registering new user is not working ,please suggest why

Comment: Do you see any error in the node log or the MongoDB log? Something like dup key? It's working fine here.

Comment: no error , and it take long time to goto http://localhost:3000/users after click on Register Button

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to say "my Windows system" and you have built a WIN32 version of node, then it is likely that the permissions related code has not yet been implemented.

I suggest that you try the Cygwin version. I have sucessfully built 0.5.0pre on Cygwin. If you don't have Cygwin, it is easy to install on XP or Win7. You don't need all of it, just the base install and the packages mentioned here: [https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)](https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29)